# Scroll bar for unordered list inside div tag

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list inside a div tag and I want the list to be scroll-able if the number of items in the list exceeds the length of the webpage.

```
<div style="width: 300px; height:100px; overflow: auto">
    <ul>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If I hardcode height as 100px, and the number of items exceed this height, a scroll bar appears. However if I make height as 100% the scroll bar does not appear. Could some one let me know where I am going wrong?

You can view the sample code on http://jsfiddle.net/xf7kjcf6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `height: 100%;` of any element, you need to ask a question that 100% of what? By defauly, user agents assign `height: auto;` to certain elements and since the parent element `height` is `auto` your `100%` does work but it's `100%` of the parent (which is set to `auto` by default) and not the viewport.

Inorder to make it 100% of the viewport you need to set `height: 100%;` of all the parent element of `div` and itself in this case it should be

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}

.a_list {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    list-style-type: disc;
}

.a_list li {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Avoid writing inline styles for your `<div>` element, move them to an external stylesheet and then use `height: 100%;` and it should work now. Also, you won't need `overflow: auto;` property as by default it will have a scroll bar.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xf7kjcf6/12/)

Note that if you add any other wrapper element to your `div` then you need to set the `height` of that wrapper element to `100%` as well.

Last but not the least, you might not be knowing about [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), so you might need that too.

Comment: Thanks! It worked due to your explanation of viewport concept! I wasn't fully aware of it. Thanks for the extra details which made it work :-)

Comment: @user1692342 You welcome, I cleaned your markup a bit, am adding the details for the same

Answer (score 1):

Without JS you can do it like this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px; height:100%; overflow: auto">
  <ul>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: While this is the right answer, there's really no need for the `*`. It changes the layout of all paragraphs, headers, blockquotes etc. Just `html, body, div {height:100%; margin:0}` would have done.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a parent of 100% height to the body/html tags to make the div a 100% of the window.  So add:

```
body, html {
 height: 100%;
}
```

And then you can change the div to 100% height as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use 100% for div then you have to use body and html 100%. normally  height auto those are not 100%.

```
html,body{
height:100%;
```

}